# Viewport meta tag in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, device-width

In viewport meta tag in CSS for achieving responsive web design we set width = device-width like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` so that the page's width equal to that of the device's width , so that users do not have to scroll to see the page but what about the height ? Does the browser infer the height based on the width and make it device-height ???

Comment: Change `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"`, the height is bonded with the width.

Comment: ok.. so even height will be equal to device-height ?

Comment: Height will increase according to content.

Comment: Yes, since by `initial-scale=1` you set the initial zoom level to 100% and if the width changes, the height will do too

Comment: Just another doubt does initial-scale=1 mean content size will be same as web page size ? so there won't be any need for zoom in/out ?

Comment: height of a webpage is irrelevant to the media upon which it is displayed. Height scrolls. Simple.

Answer (score 3):

The correct `meta` tag for a responsive website is the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device. The `initial-scale=1` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser. You don't need to set a specific height, since `window` dimensions are always both scaled on change. But in case, you can change the content of the `meta` tag with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

Have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) if you have more doubts.

Comment: I looked but still initial-scale=1 is not clear to me , does it mean content size will be same as web page size ? so there won't be any need for zoom in/out ?

Comment: If you set the `width` equal to the `device-width` and `initial-scale=1`, it means that the window is of the same dimension of the device screen and the scale is 100% (which means that does not need to be zoom in/out). If you change the dimensions of the screen, then the size will also change since the width is bonded with the device dimensions and the scale will always remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)

Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag then hope clear everything.